# Because it only shows the id and not the table info in my index.php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Currently I am making my products appear their status "available" or "out of stock" create a new table called "estado" in my database ... In my products table add a new column called "estado_id" where it is stored in what state is the product.

Database Images:

[ESTADO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iml5n.png)

[PRODUCTOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm5Vi.png)

Then when placing it so that it is shown in the list of my products in index.php it appears is only the ID of the state table. For example in the image below it says "1" and I need the status of the product to appear, to say if it is available or out of stock.

[PRODUCT IN INDEX.PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvNWo.png)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvNWo.png)

index.php

```
    <div class="productos">
        <a href="productos/producto.php?id=<?php echo $productos['id']?>">
  <img src="<?php echo '/images/' . $productos['image']; ?>" class="img-test">
  <p class="text-test"><?php echo $productos['title']?></p>
            

            <p class="status"><?php echo $productos['tipo_id']; ?></p>
 
            
            
        </a>
</div>
```

productos.php

```
<?php 

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/database/db.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/helpers/validatePost.php');

$table = 'productos';
$categorias = selectAll('categorias');
$estado = selectAll('estado');

$errors = array();
$id = '';
$title = '';
$body = '';
$estadoid = '';
$topic_id = '';

$productos = selectAll($table);


if (isset($_POST['add-post'])) {
    $_POST['topic_id']=serialize($_POST['topic_id']);
    $errors = validatePost($_POST);
    
    if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        $image_name = time() . '_' . $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $destination = "../../images/" . $image_name;
        
        $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        
        if ($result){
            $_POST['image'] = $image_name;
        } else {
            array_push($errors, "¡Algo fallo al subir la imagen!");
        }
        
        
    } else {
      array_push($errors, "¡Necesitas subir una imagen!");
    }
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        unset($_POST['add-post']);
        $post_id = create($table, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Post creado correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic_id'];
        $estadoid = $_POST['estado_id'];
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $post = selectOne($table, ['id' => $id]);
}

if (isset($_GET['del_id'])){
    $id = $_GET['del_id'];    
    $count = delete($table, $id);
    $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Post eliminado correctamente!';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['update-post'])){
    $_POST['topic_id']=serialize(array_values($_POST['topic_id']));
    $_POST['estado_id']=serialize($_POST['estado_id']);
    $errors = validateEdit($_POST); 
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        unset($_POST['update-post'], $_POST['id']);
        $post_id = update($table, $id, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Post actualizado correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/topics/index.php');
        exit();        
    } else {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic_id'];
        $estadoid = $_POST['estado_id'];
}
} 
?>
```

db.php

```
<?php

session_start();
require('connect.php');

function dd($value)
{
    echo "<pre>", print_r($value, true), "</pre>";
    die();
}


function executeQuery($sql, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $values = array_values($data);
    $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}


function selectAll($table, $conditions = [])
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    if (empty($conditions)) {
        $sql = $sql . " ORDER BY id DESC";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;    
    } else {
        // $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username='ElVictox' AND admin=1";
        
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
        
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $values = array_values($conditions);
        $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
        $stmt->bind_param($types, $values);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;
    }
}



function selectOne($table, $conditions)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ";

        $i = 0;
                foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
               $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $sql = $sql . " LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $conditions);
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        return $records;
    }

function create($table, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    $id = $stmt->insert_id;
    return $id;
    
}

function update($table, $id, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    
    $sql = $sql . " WHERE id=?";
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}


function delete($table, $id)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id=?";
      
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, ['id' => $id]);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}
```

Comment: You will need to reduce this code to a [mre] if you wish someone would be able to help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a left join to the second table, something like:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.name as estado FROM productos AS t1 LEFT JOIN estados as t2 ON (t1.estado_id = t2.id)
```

Then on the html:

```
<p class="status"><?php echo $productos['estado']; ?></p>
```

Comment: Hi, in where would I add that SELECT?

Comment: On the selectAll and selectOne functions ($sql variable), and adjust to what you currently do there.
Like:

function selectAll($table, $conditions = [])
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    if($table == "produtos") $sql = "SELECT t1.*, t2.name as estado FROM productos AS t1 LEFT JOIN estados as t2 ON (t1.estado_id = t2.id)";